# Problemas al ejecutar mi script de voto js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Cuando ejecuto el input(BTN) cuenta todo las filas de los productos de la DB, no me esta contando cuando selecciono solo un producto específico:

Mi tabla se llama "productos"

```
id  Nombre  precio  stock     ruta           voto
1   Camisas $5.00   35    img/camisa.jpg     2
2   casacas $55.00  55    img/casacas.jpg    2
3   boxer   $67.00  20    img/boxer.jpg      2
4   zapatos $45.00  15    img/zapatos.jpg    2
```

script PHP "voto.php"

```
<?php
require_once("conn.php");
$strSQL_Result  = mysqli_query($connection,"select `voto` from 
`productos` where id=id");
$row            = mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL_Result);

$voto       = $row['voto'];
if($_POST)
{
if(isset($_COOKIE["counter_gang"]))
{
    echo "-1";
    exit;
}

setcookie("counter_gang", "votos", time()+3600*24);
if(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['up']) == 'voto')
{
    $update = "`voto`=`voto`+1";
}

mysqli_query($connection,"update `productos` set $update where `id`=`id`");
echo 1;
exit;   
}
?>
```

Mi script JS "sumarVoto.js"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#votar").removeAttr("disabled");
$('#votar').click(function(e)
 {
    var val = parseInt($("#votar").val(), 10);
    $.post("voto.php", {up:"voto"},function(data)
    {
        if(data==1)
        {
            $("#status").html("Voto Exitosamente!!");
            val = val+1;
            $("#votar").val(val);
            $("#votar").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#votar").css("background-image","url(voto1.png)");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#status").html("Ya vote!!");
        }
    })
  });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input  id="votar" type="submit" value="votar">
  <span id="status">...</span>
</div>
```

Cuando ejecuto el input normal, se ejecuta pero el error es que  suma todo las filas de la tabla "productos"  y tampoco me funciona los COOKIE

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene varios problemas. Dejando de lado dudas sobre la mejor forma de hacer las cosas, y limitándonos a los errores directos, tienes:

1. En tu javascript, aunque buscas el valor de `#votar` que asumo debería ser el id del producto votado (pero no estoy seguro de ello), no lo envías al servidor. Tu llamada es `$.post("voto.php", {up:"voto"})`, es decir, no le envías más que la cadena "voto". El servidor no sabe a qué estás votando.
2. En el servidor, en cada query que haces añades un `where id=id` como único test. Ese test es siempre cierto, porque para todas las lineas, la columna `id` es igual a sí misma. Por tanto, recibes o actualizas todas las lineas.